# Example of IPC communication between a daemon running as root and another non-root process using Mach messages for macOS

Tags: c++, macos, mach, xnu, launch-daemon

I'm trying to understand the low-level mechanism of IPC using [Mach messages](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/Mach/Mach.html) between a launch daemon (running as root) and another process, running in a user-content.

Assuming the following data structs:

```
struct MACH_MSG_BASE
{
    mach_msg_header_t hdr;
    mach_msg_body_t body;
};


struct MACH_MSG_UINT32
{
    MACH_MSG_BASE base;
    
    unsigned int val;      //Sending this value as a test
};
```

So I'm running the following code in the daemon:

```
//Server:

//No error checks for brevity
mach_port_t port = MACH_PORT_NULL;
mach_port_t task = mach_task_self();

mach_port_allocate(task,
                   MACH_PORT_RIGHT_RECEIVE,
                   &port);

mach_port_insert_right(task,
                       port,
                       port,
                       MACH_MSG_TYPE_MAKE_SEND);

MACH_MSG_UINT32 msg = {};
msg.base.hdr.msgh_local_port = port;
msg.base.hdr.msgh_size = sizeof(msg.base);
        
mach_msg(&msg.base.hdr,
         MACH_RCV_MSG,
         0,
         sizeof(msg),
         port,
         MACH_MSG_TIMEOUT_NONE,
         MACH_PORT_NULL);
```

When I run the code above, it goes into a waiting mode at the `mach_msg` call, as I would expect.

But then, the first issue - how do you get the port number of the daemon from another process? I'm assuming using `task_for_pid`, as such:

```
//Client(s):

//No error checks for brevity
mach_port_t port = MACH_PORT_NULL;
mach_port_t task;
task_for_pid(mach_task_self(), server_pid, &task);  //I guess we get server_pid by daemon process name?

mach_port_allocate(task,
                   MACH_PORT_RIGHT_RECEIVE,
                   &port);

MACH_MSG_UINT32 msg = {};
    
msg.base.hdr.msgh_remote_port = _port;
msg.base.hdr.msgh_local_port = MACH_PORT_NULL;
msg.base.hdr.msgh_bits = MACH_MSGH_BITS_REMOTE(MACH_MSG_TYPE_MAKE_SEND);
msg.base.hdr.msgh_size = sizeof(msg.base);
    
msg.val = 0x12345678;
    
mach_msg(&msg.base.hdr,
         MACH_SEND_MSG,
         sizeof(msg),
         0,
         MACH_PORT_NULL,
         MACH_MSG_TIMEOUT_NONE,
         MACH_PORT_NULL);
```

But when I run the code above, the `mach_msg` returns 0x10000003 or `MACH_SEND_INVALID_DEST`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`task_for_pid` almost never works these days, Apple has significantly restricted it for security reasons.

The way to find a Mach server is for it to register a port name, and for clients to look up the port in either the privileged or user's namespace. For a launch daemon or agent, you specify the ports it offers in the `MachServices` section of the launchd plist:

```
<key>MachServices</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.example.mydaemon.MyMachService1</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.example.mydaemon.MyMachService2</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
```

The client would then look up these ports to obtain a send right using the bootstrap API:

```
kern_return_t kr = bootstrap_look_up(bootstrap_port, "com.example.mydaemon.MyMachService1", &service_port);
```

All of that said, working with low level Mach ports is extremely cumbersome. I strongly recommend using XPC instead unless you have some legacy or system level Mach service you need to interface with. With XPC you still register the `MachServices` in the launchd plist, the code side is a lot easier to work with though. As you're using C++, your starting point would be the `xpc_connection_create_mach_service()` function.

Comment: Thanks. I need to try that. Unfortunately there are so few C++ examples on how to use XPC just for the IPC between a launch daemon and a launch agent. The same is unfortunately true for the Mach messages. So if you can link any I would appreciate it.

Comment: I'm also curious about the launchd plist - why did you use two entries: com.example.mydaemon.MyMachService1 and com.example.mydaemon.MyMachService2?

Comment: Yeah, this is why I gave you the clue about `xpc_connection_create_mach_service`, I expect it might be easier to find examples using that as a keyword. I provided two names of Mach services to give you an example of how you use more than one. You can implement any number including 1, 2 was an arbitrary choice.

Comment: Note that offering an XPC service on a privileged daemon opens up a potential security vulnerability; by default, ANYONE is allowed to connect and send your daemon messages, so if that could cause trouble, the way to guard against it is usually to enforce a code signing entitlement check: verify if the incoming connection is coming from a process with an executable signed by you. (Which presumably itself has some kind of hardened interface to stop the user performing destructive operations without an admin password for example.)

Comment: Yes, it would work ... Unless someone injects their (malicious) code into my signed user process. (But that's another question. At this point I need to make the basic IPC work.)

Comment: Question: from the server side, how do I associate my port with, say, `com.example.mydaemon.MyMachService1`?

Comment: Code injection is prevented by using the so-called "hardened runtime" which once again is something you can check is active. Both sides of the connection use [`xpc_connection_create_mach_service`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xpc/1448783-xpc_connection_create_mach_servi?language=objc), the listener (server) needs to set the `XPC_CONNECTION_MACH_SERVICE_LISTENER` flag and set up an event handler for accepting incoming connections. The (reverse DNS) mach port name is specified in the `name` parameter, again on both sides, and on the listener side must match one of those in the plist